# Error: Multiple markers

Tags: java, datainputstream

I have just started working on java  n working on getting input from the user  and have written the code

```
public class swap  {    
    public static void main(String[]args )  {       
        DataInputStream joi=new DataInputStream (System.in); 
        System.out.println("enter two integer values"); 
        int a=Integer.parseInt(joi.readLine()); 
        int b=Integer.parseInt(joi.readLine());             
    }  
 }
```

and while compiling  it gives me the error:

> multiple markers in this line at the 9th line

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `DataInputStream` for user input, use [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).